# Any nice examples of small cancellation theory appearing in applied mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, gr.group-theory, applications, algorithms, cryptography

Are there any nice discussions of applications of small cancellation theory, or other cases of the word problem, in applied mathematics or algorithms for seemingly non-group theoretic problems?

I suppose two candidates are [Anshel–Anshel–Goldfeld key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anshel%E2%80%93Anshel%E2%80%93Goldfeld_key_exchange) and [braid group based cryptography](http://www.cs.ut.ee/~lipmaa/crypto/link/public/braid/index.php).

Comment: Jeff, I got your email and replied. If you do not get my reply, please let me know, here I guess. I made this a "favorite" question, I will automatically be able to find this.   

Comment: Braid group based cryptography was popular at the very beginning of the 21st century when the Anshel-Anshel-Goldfeld key exchange was originally invented, but today people view braid group cryptography as insecure.

Answer (score 6):

The group-based cryptography is a very active area now. There are books (eg [Group-based Cryptography](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-7643-8827-0)) and a  special journal, [Groups Complexity Cryptology](https://www.degruyter.com/journal/key/gcc/html).

As another application, one can reformulate the problem P=NP as "Is it true that every finitely presented group with polynomial Dehn function has word problem solvable deterministically in polynomial time?" (see the paper *Isoperimetric and isodiametric functions of groups* [arXiv:math/9811105](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9811105)).

Small cancelation itself is not used much in any of these areas, but many ideas are inspired by the classical small cancelation theory.